# Why public synonyms become invalid

Tags: oracle11g

I have 2 packages and 2 public synonyms for those packages. There are dependencies between those packages. If I make changes to any of those packages and compile them then packages are compiled and valid (specs and bodies) but both synonyms are invalid. I know I can recompile synonyms but how to avoid this please? Is there a way to keep all objects compiled? Thank you.

Comment: If you call the procedure after the syn shows invalid, does it change back to valid?

Comment: No, it does not. I have to open package 1 where I have references to procedure that is in package 2, comment that procedure, compile, then uncomment, compile, then it works. Thank you.